# How do I access the Behavior Params (Behavior Bricks asset package) in a Unity3D C# script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm testing out the Behavior Bricks asset package for Unity3D. And I want to access the value "closeDistance" in the behavior params in the [Behavior Executoner component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl6TX.png)

Do anyone know if it is possible to do this in a C# script?

Comment: Why don't you ask the [authors](http://www.padaonegames.com) of [Behaviour Bricks](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/behavior-bricks-74816) -> `contact@padaonegames.com`